# drupal 8 enable twig debug not working?

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

I'm trying to get my head around this: I don't know why the twig debug isn't working: 
Drupal version **8.2.6**

<kbd>Folder structure</kbd>

[image: File structure] .

<kbd>Folder permissions</kbd>

[image: Folder permissions]

<kbd>Settings.php</kbd>

```
$settings['hash_salt'] = 'DEVELOPMENT_SALT';
$settings['update_free_access'] = FALSE;
$settings['file_public_base_url'] = 'http://localhost/files';
$settings['file_public_path'] = 'sites/default/files';
$settings['file_private_path'] = 'sites/default/private';
$settings['file_scan_ignore_directories'] = [
  'node_modules',
  'bower_components',
];
if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/../development/settings.development.php'))     {
  include __DIR__ . '/../development/settings.development.php';
}
```

<kbd>/../development/settings.development.php</kbd>

```
assert_options(ASSERT_ACTIVE, TRUE);
\Drupal\Component\Assertion\Handle::register();

/**
 * Enable local development services.
 */
$settings['container_yamls'][] = __DIR__ . '/development.services.yml';

$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'database' => 'dbname',
  'username' => 'dbusername',
  'password' => 'pw',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => '127.0.0.1',
  'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);

$settings['hash_salt'] = 'DEVELOPMENT';

$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';
$config['system.performance']['css']['preprocess'] = FALSE;
$config['system.performance']['js']['preprocess'] = FALSE;
$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';
$settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] =     'cache.backend.null';
$settings['extension_discovery_scan_tests'] = TRUE;
$settings['rebuild_access'] = TRUE;
$settings['skip_permissions_hardening'] = TRUE;
```

<kbd>development.services.yml</kbd>

```
parameters:
  http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: true
  twig.config:
    debug: true
    auto_reload: true
    cache: false
services:
  cache.backend.null:
    class: Drupal\Core\Cache\NullBackendFactory
```

Things I have checked/done:

- Checked if all these files are loaded -> They are.
- Checked the indentation of the development.services.yml -> Checks out.
- Cleared all the different caches, rebuild them, ...

If I change a template, it changes, but no twig debugging.

What is odd:
sites/default/files AND sites/default/private are not used by Drupal.

Comment: I suggest that you can ask your question on http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just in case what do you expect of the debugging?
In most cases the answer of vijay is enough to show you the template information (if you view source). If you want to show available variables you wil of course need to add {{ dump() }} to your twig template (be careful when you have much data this can give you a memory error in that case coderate's answer should be helpfull)

Answer (score 16):

I'd recommend against renaming the development.services.yml file to services.yml because that would cause all of your development code/config/settings to apply and run on production environments. Instead, use the development files as designed.

Here's our standard setup:

`/sites/default/settings.php` (in version control) contains the following at the very bottom so that we only load development stuff on instances that should have it. e.g. NOT production:

```
/**
 * Load local development override configuration, if available.
 *
 * Keep this code block at the end of this file to take full effect.
 */
if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/settings.local.php')) {
  include __DIR__ . '/settings.local.php';
}
```

Our `/sites/default/settings.local.php` (not in version control) contains at least the following:

```
<?php

/**
 * Disable css and js preprocessing.
 */
$config['system.performance']['css']['preprocess'] = FALSE;
$config['system.performance']['js']['preprocess'] = FALSE;

/**
 * Disable Render Cache and Dynamic Page Cache.
 */
$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';
$settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';

/**
 * Enable local development services.
 */
$settings['container_yamls'][] = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/development.services.yml';

/**
 * Enable access to rebuild.php.
 */
$settings['rebuild_access'] = TRUE;
```

And finally, our `/sites/development.services.yml` (in version control) file contains this:

```
# Local development services.
#
# To activate this feature, follow the instructions at the top of the
# 'example.settings.local.php' file, which sits next to this file.
parameters:
  http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: true
  twig.config:
    debug: true
    auto_reload: true
    cache: false
services:
  cache.backend.null:
    class: Drupal\Core\Cache\NullBackendFactory
```

This has worked really well for us.

Comment: This was extremely useful. I wasn't careful with the file paths on my first attempt, so if you try this and are still having trouble, double check your paths.

Answer (score 5):

To enable Twig debug, you need to copy("default.services.yml") and rename it to "services.yml". And set "debug: false" to true.

E.g: services.yml

```
parameters:
  session.storage.options:
    # Default ini options for sessions.
    #
    # Some distributions of Linux (most notably Debian) ship their PHP
    # installations with garbage collection (gc) disabled. Since Drupal depends
    # on PHP's garbage collection for clearing sessions, ensure that garbage
    # collection occurs by using the most common settings.
    # @default 1
    gc_probability: 1
    # @default 100
    gc_divisor: 100
    #
    # Set session lifetime (in seconds), i.e. the time from the user's last
    # visit to the active session may be deleted by the session garbage
    # collector. When a session is deleted, authenticated users are logged out,
    # and the contents of the user's $_SESSION variable is discarded.
    # @default 200000
    gc_maxlifetime: 200000
    #
    # Set session cookie lifetime (in seconds), i.e. the time from the session
    # is created to the cookie expires, i.e. when the browser is expected to
    # discard the cookie. The value 0 means "until the browser is closed".
    # @default 2000000
    cookie_lifetime: 2000000
    #
    # Drupal automatically generates a unique session cookie name based on the
    # full domain name used to access the site. This mechanism is sufficient
    # for most use-cases, including multi-site deployments. However, if it is
    # desired that a session can be reused across different subdomains, the
    # cookie domain needs to be set to the shared base domain. Doing so assures
    # that users remain logged in as they cross between various subdomains.
    # To maximize compatibility and normalize the behavior across user agents,
    # the cookie domain should start with a dot.
    #
    # @default none
    # cookie_domain: '.example.com'
    #
  twig.config:
    # Twig debugging:
    #
    # When debugging is enabled:
    # - The markup of each Twig template is surrounded by HTML comments that
    #   contain theming information, such as template file name suggestions.
    # - Note that this debugging markup will cause automated tests that directly
    #   check rendered HTML to fail. When running automated tests, 'debug'
    #   should be set to FALSE.
    # - The dump() function can be used in Twig templates to output information
    #   about template variables.
    # - Twig templates are automatically recompiled whenever the source code
    #   changes (see auto_reload below).
    #
    # For more information about debugging Twig templates, see
    # https://www.drupal.org/node/1906392.
    #
    # Not recommended in production environments
    # @default false
    debug: true
    # Twig auto-reload:
    #
    # Automatically recompile Twig templates whenever the source code changes.
    # If you don't provide a value for auto_reload, it will be determined
    # based on the value of debug.
    #
    # Not recommended in production environments
    # @default null
    auto_reload: null
    # Twig cache:
    #
    # By default, Twig templates will be compiled and stored in the filesystem
    # to increase performance. Disabling the Twig cache will recompile the
    # templates from source each time they are used. In most cases the
    # auto_reload setting above should be enabled rather than disabling the
    # Twig cache.
    #
    # Not recommended in production environments
    # @default true
    cache: true
  renderer.config:
    # Renderer required cache contexts:
    #
    # The Renderer will automatically associate these cache contexts with every
    # render array, hence varying every render array by these cache contexts.
    #
    # @default ['languages:language_interface', 'theme', 'user.permissions']
    required_cache_contexts: ['languages:language_interface', 'theme', 'user.permissions']
    # Renderer automatic placeholdering conditions:
    #
    # Drupal allows portions of the page to be automatically deferred when
    # rendering to improve cache performance. That is especially helpful for
    # cache contexts that vary widely, such as the active user. On some sites
    # those may be different, however, such as sites with only a handful of
    # users. If you know what the high-cardinality cache contexts are for your
    # site, specify those here. If you're not sure, the defaults are fairly safe
    # in general.
    #
    # For more information about rendering optimizations see
    # https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/render/arrays/cacheability#optimizing
    auto_placeholder_conditions:
      # Max-age at or below which caching is not considered worthwhile.
      #
      # Disable by setting to -1.
      #
      # @default 0
      max-age: 0
      # Cache contexts with a high cardinality.
      #
      # Disable by setting to [].
      #
      # @default ['session', 'user']
      contexts: ['session', 'user']
      # Tags with a high invalidation frequency.
      #
      # Disable by setting to [].
      #
      # @default []
      tags: []
  # Cacheability debugging:
  #
  # Responses with cacheability metadata (CacheableResponseInterface instances)
  # get X-Drupal-Cache-Tags and X-Drupal-Cache-Contexts headers.
  #
  # For more information about debugging cacheable responses, see
  # https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/response/cacheable-response-interface
  #
  # Not recommended in production environments
  # @default false
  http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: false
  factory.keyvalue:
    {}
    # Default key/value storage service to use.
    # @default keyvalue.database
    # default: keyvalue.database
    # Collection-specific overrides.
    # state: keyvalue.database
  factory.keyvalue.expirable:
    {}
    # Default key/value expirable storage service to use.
    # @default keyvalue.database.expirable
    # default: keyvalue.database.expirable
  # Allowed protocols for URL generation.
  filter_protocols:
    - http
    - https
    - ftp
    - news
    - nntp
    - tel
    - telnet
    - mailto
    - irc
    - ssh
    - sftp
    - webcal
    - rtsp

   # Configure Cross-Site HTTP requests (CORS).
   # Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS
   # for more information about the topic in general.
   # Note: By default the configuration is disabled.
  cors.config:
    enabled: false
    # Specify allowed headers, like 'x-allowed-header'.
    allowedHeaders: []
    # Specify allowed request methods, specify ['*'] to allow all possible ones.
    allowedMethods: []
    # Configure requests allowed from specific origins.
    allowedOrigins: ['*']
    # Sets the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header.
    exposedHeaders: false
    # Sets the Access-Control-Max-Age header.
    maxAge: false
    # Sets the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header.
    supportsCredentials: false
```

Answer (score 3):

Twig Debuggin wasn't working as expected, I did all the thing you did and it didn't work. So I searched for debug:false in all the site and found this file: core/core.services.xml

I changed the values there and it worked!

It's not a good way to do this because we are modifying the core, but It will help someone with this problem!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `cache` option to **true** on your `development.services.yml` file.
Something like this:

```
services:
  cache.backend.null:
    class: Drupal\Core\Cache\NullBackendFactory
parameters:
  twig.config:
    debug: true
    auto_reload: true
    cache: true
```

After you clear your cache and open some pages that you want to debug you will see that in `files/php/twig` some `.php` files will be created, like the bellow image:

[image: twig-debug]

on these pages will debug normally as you debug a `.php` file.

There is an article on the Acquia blog that help you make this configuration and debug using Xdebug and the PhpStorm IDE that you can on the link [Debugging TWIG templates in Drupal 8 with PhpStorm and XDebug](https://dev.acquia.com/blog/debugging-twig-templates-in-drupal-8-with-phpstorm-and-xdebug/25/08/2016/16586)

Answer (score 1):

Just duplicate `default.services.yml` to `services.yml`. So, `core.services.xml` will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

For most of you, including this line **at the bottom** of your `settings.php` file will do the work:

```
$settings['container_yamls'][] = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/development.services.yml';
```

#### More details

If you already set debug for Twig and nothing works, you are modifying the wrong file.

First, ensure that Drupal is parsing the services file you are modifying. One easy way of doing this is by adding bad YML formatting to the services file you are working with, then try to clear caches, and Drupal should complain like "Unable to parse".

If Drupal doesn't complain despite adding bad YML formatting, it means that the file is not being parsed; hence, it doesn't matter if you change it.

Appending the line I mentioned to your `settings.php` ensures you are adding the development services configuration, which most of the time has the following contents:

```
# Local development services.
#
# To activate this feature, follow the instructions at the top of the
# 'example.settings.local.php' file, which sits next to this file.
parameters:
  http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: true
  twig.config:
    # @default false
    debug: true
    # @default null
    auto_reload: true
    # @default true
    cache: false
services:
  cache.backend.null:
    class: Drupal\Core\Cache\NullBackendFactory
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Mix](https://www.drupal.org/project/mix) module to disable all these caches with just one click. No manual copy/paste and file editing works.
[image]